# Who do I contact with a question about the ESTA?

Tags: usa, esta

My nationality makes me eligible for the ESTA and I have applied for the ESTA successfully 2 years ago.

However, I am not sure how to answer one of the new questions in the ESTA questionnaire (added somewhere in 2016 I think). Who can I consult about this?

I have tried the U.S. consulate in Amsterdam, but their phone computer states explicitly that they cannot provide support on answering any questions concerning the ESTA. I got hold of a USA visa support desk, but they could only redirect me to the general US travel website and also were not allowed to answer my question.

Comment: There's at least [some anecdotal evidence](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66719/traveling-to-us-with-esta-but-have-an-iranian-father-do-i-need-a-visa-instead/66749#66749) that people have been able to obtain straight answers by calling CBP at +1-202-344-3710.

Comment: You could also ask the question here. Someone may be able to give you a link to an official source that answers it.

Comment: @ZachLipton While that is certainly an option I thought the current broader question would be helpful to more people. The real question I have is quite specific (I think) and would probably be not of much use to a large audience.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [US Embassy in Austria](https://at.usembassy.gov/visas/visa-waiver-program/):

> Visa Waiver Program travelers with inquiries about their ESTA registration can first visit the U.S. Department of Homeland Security/Customs and Border Patrol (DHS/CBP) info center at: http://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/esta. Should a person need further information after consulting the website, **one may call the ESTA Help Line at +1-202-344-3710** Monday-Friday 0800-1600 Eastern Time (local time: 02:00 pm to 10:00 pm).