# Can I also get a VISA if I already succesfully applied for an ESTA?

Tags: visas, usa, esta

So I already posted something about this but I rather be on the safe side, hence this post.

Have a valid ESTA which has been approved in January 2020. My dad is Iranian, but I don't have any ties whatsoever - never lived there, never been there, no passport. I want to travel to the USA in September.

However, I don't want the borders to try to get a reason why they should not allow me so I am doubting to get a Non-Immigrant visa as well. Should I get a Non-Immigrant VISA 'just to be sure' or will that be seen as double (as I also have an ESTA) and will they reject me because of that?

**EDIT**: As I did my research and asked advice, I would like to tell the following. For people who think they are in the same situation as me, I suggest **not to take a VISA**. They are suitable for an ESTA, so no need to apply for a VISA as well. It can only complicate things and you can only dig yourself into a hole. For my situation, the Dutch law says people who are born after 1 January 1985  with a Dutch mother (suitable for me), are automatically Dutch citizens. Iran doesn't even know that I exist so USA is not likely to care.

Answer (score 5):

You can get a visa and there is no problem with that, but there is also no real reason to do so. Your ESTA is fine for travel to the US, and a visa provides no more guarantee of being admitted than the ESTA does. The only current reason to get a visa instead of the ESTA is if you need to stay more than 90 days continuously.

Comment: Hi,

But they won't think I am an 'Iranian national' because of my dad? PS: Iran doesn't even know I exist - no note of birth at the Consulate of Iran. I know a VISA still doesn't 100% allow you to enter, but it is suited for 'iranian persons' that are Dutch.

Comment: Several people have already explained to you that the US will not consider you an Iranian national in this circumstance. You would need an Iranian passport, or at least to have traveled to Iran at some time in your life, before the US will be interested.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks and that is correct - the only reason I was doubting was because of this reason: "As others have pointed out, the immigration officer was most likely wrong to say that my uncle doesn't need a visa. And as Henning Makholm answered here, the safest option would definitely have been to apply for a visa for myself as well"

This is same the situation as **mine**: [https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66719/traveling-to-us-with-esta-but-have-an-iranian-father-do-i-need-a-visa-instead/66739#66739]